# Grails Inline Plugin causes packaging error in grails 2.3.8

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-plugin

I have a Grails project with a sub-module included as inline plugin. In my BuildConfig.groovy I have the following line to include this module:

```
grails.plugin.location.'my-submodule' = "../my-submodule"
```

which points to the correct directory and has been correctly handled using grails 2.3.7.

After upgrading to Grails 2.3.8 the gradle build fails with an error message saying that it looks for the submodule in the directory:

C:\my\source\dir\main-module\C:\Users\MyUser.grails\2.3.8\projects\main-module\stage\WEB-INF\plugins\sub-module-0.1\plugin.xml

Where can I set the path, such that the correct path is used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is caused by a bug in grails 2.3.8
(http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11360)

A workaround is to include the following line of config in the BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
```

to set the path explicitely